# SVG Map and show branches

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a SVG Iran map with province and I want to show branches in every provinces
when I click on every province show 2 column data include name of branches and branches information.
we have some branches in some cities, for example in Tehran we have 5 branches and in another city only one branches, in this js code only show information from one branch!
in below code

```
const ardabil = new MapItem('ardabil', 'استان اردبیل', 'branches name', 'branches info')
```

but I can't set information for three or four branches names and branches informations

for example when I click on Tehran province, we will see:
in first col: name of branch 1
in second col: information of branch 1

although I want to show when click on Tehran province

```
row:
col 1: name of branch 1
col 2: info of branch 1

row
col 1: name of branch 2
col 2: info of branch 2

row
col 1: name of branch 3
col 2: info of branch 3
```

in some provinces we have 10 branches and in some provinces we have 1 branch
in some provinces we have not any branches

you can see my html,js code:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/Josepek/pen/jOpjGzj)

regards

Comment: Pardon me, but I still don't get what you mean by "branches" by means of their visual relation and content. Please try to provide a stripped down example (e.g containing 3 provinces)  and/or an illustration/mockup what you're trying to display.

Comment: I work in a brokerage and we have branches in different cities I plan to display branch information such as addresses and phone numbers by clicking on each province In this code, it is only possible to display information about one branch in each city, and I plan to display any desired number by changing the code